# Problems with npm run dev(Error: spawn undefined\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell ENOENT)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, powershell, visual-studio-code, vite

when I run command "npm run dev" then this error occurs.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enuH3.png)

I am expecting that to my after running command "npm run dev" localhost:3000 will start and my browser will open and code will run smoothly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ENOENT means "no such file or directory".

As you can see, it's trying to open a path starting with "undefined", which clearly doesn't exist in your system.

That means that in the string of the path you're trying to open there is an undefined variable.

My bet is that you are using a variable to get the current path of your directory.

Can I see the code in which you create this string of the path ?

Comment: i am just running command in powershell then this issue occurs. I also check path of powershell in my CMD through "where powershell" everything is fine, it is showing there path. Even I also run backend folder through powershell it runs fine but in frontend part only this issue occurs.

Comment: Basically I am trying to work on open source project IDURAR. whose repo link is https://github.com/idurar/idurar-erp-crm.It is basically MERN stack project. It contains 2 parts frontend and backend. I have setup backend part. But in frontend part I am getting this issue and the issue is Error: spawn undefined\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell ENOENT. I have run backend part through powershell it works fine but in frontend it is showing this error.

Comment: @Amitsingh I guess they are trying to access an environment variable that isn't set, thus having "undefined" in the path...

Is there a README or some docs to setup their project ? Maybe you're missing a .env